# how to disable Flash uploader in Tinymce in magento 1.6

Tags: tinymce, magento-1.6, magento

There is some issue with the flash uploader in magento site I am building. I got a extension that changes the flash uploader in the catalog sectiong. But it did not change it in CMS,Block section.

Any idea how to disable flash uploader and enable normal html uploader in TINYMCE editor ?

Thanks
Abhi

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the URL below:

[magento customize tinymce](http://www.raisereview.com/magento-customize-tinymce/)

You can add features in tinymce or remove features in tinymce.